# Intellij - how do I add a text file to the resources

Tags: intellij-idea

I am reading a `*.properties` file using `properties.load` and a file name.

I want to add the properties file to the jar or to the classpath.

1. How do add a file to the jar?
2. How do I read from the jar?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Place the file in the source folder, it will be copied to the output and added to the jar together with the classes according to `Settings` | `Compiler` | `Resource Patterns`.

To load the file in your app use something like:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
InputStream is = this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/file.properties");
props.load(is);
```